# creating databases in mysql error

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to work with mysql client and have successfully created a database and table in that database using commands:
mysql>Create Database test;
mysql>Use test;
mysql>Create table test_table
( name varchar(30)
);

I got successfully created messages for all the above commands
mysql> Show databases
displays my database : test

As per my understanding, this new database which I have created should be stored inside 
c:/users/programfiles/mysql/data/

But I am unable to find the location of this created database.
Could some one please help me??? I am at this issue from a super long time :(

I am working on windows 7 and mysql workbench 5.2.33

Thank you,
J

Comment: Why do you need to know the location of the database files? For most purposes being able to connect to a db is sufficient. What is more most often even if you know the position of those files it is no help, because you can't read those files, even copying them and trying to restore on another server may fail.

Comment: I dont think c:/users/programfiles/mysql/data/ is the right path? I can't remember the exact extension but I am sure you have to dig deeper a level - and I am pretty sure they are stored in a /bin folder

Comment: hi, i basically wanted to import my .frm files into the directory where my database gets created to access tables inside the .frm file. I have no idea how to do it otherwise. If any idea please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually importing/exporting tables is done with SQL scripts. Those can be generated automatically. Stop trying to do this with files - even if you find the right folder it won't work. This is not the way to do that kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

check for file `my.ini` in mysql server installation. the search for string `datadir`, the value should point you to data directory.

Comment: I tried. could not find datadir inside mysql installation folder.